# aiboビジュアルプログラミングでchangeposture-standエラー

Tags: python, aibo-visual-programming

アイボビジュアルプログラミングを使って動かそうとすると、

> changeposture-stand:動作を実行できませんでした

という表示が下の方から出てきて使うことができません。
使えるように教えてください。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　python タグがついていますが、Python から使える aibo API の話か、aibo 用のビジュアルプログラミング環境の話かどちらでしょうか？　また、こちらのエラーは何かしらプログラムを作ったら出てきたものでしょうか。もしそうであれば実際のプログラムの説明（スクリーンショットなど）があると嬉しいです。質問文下の「編集」から追記いただければと思います。

Answer (score 1):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

aibo ビジュアルプログラミングの画面で
「動作を実行できませんでした」と表示される場合、
aibo が何らかの理由で、ふるまいなどの動作を開始できていません。

aibo ビジュアルプログラミングのブロックを実行する前に下記をご確認の上、実行してください。

- aibo の電源が入っており、ネットワークに接続されていること
- aibo が倒れていたり、ひっくり返っていたり、無理な姿勢ではないこと
- aibo が脱力状態（関節の力が抜けて動けない状態）ではないこと
- aibo を抱きあげていたり、持ち上あげた直後だったりではないこと

脱力状態からの復帰方法や、aibo の動きがおかしい場合の対処については、
以下の aibo ヘルプガイドをご参照ください。

- aibo の動きがおかしい場合の対処について
  https://knowledge.support.sony.jp/electronics/support/articles/00203957

  > aiboが動かない、関節の力が抜けて脱力状態になってしまった、目（瞳）が表示されないなど、
  >   動きがおかしいときは、以下の操作を順番にお試しいただき改善するかご確認ください。
  >
  > 手順1：一度スリープ状態にしてから、復帰させる
  >   手順2：一度電源を切り、再起動させる
  >   手順3：強制終了の操作を行う
- aibo が何度も脱力する場合の対処について
  https://knowledge.support.sony.jp/electronics/support/articles/00203465

  > 脱力したまま力が入らない場合は、以下の手順でaiboの再起動をお試しください。
  >
  > 1.aiboの首の後ろにあるパワーボタン（a）をゆっくり2秒間押したままにして、電源を切ります。
  >   2.再度、パワーボタンをゆっくり2秒間押したままにして、電源を入れます。
  >   ※電源オン状態になるまで、しばらく時間がかかりますので、そのままお待ちください。

今後とも aibo ビジュアルプログラミングをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム